# How to find spcific parameter value from the job in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using the below command to find out the script used in job step.
Requirement :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(command, 44, 13),
       command
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
WHERE command LIKE '%--Should provide the default location%';
```

In the job I would like to find the specific parameter value.
Lets assume in job step I have a command like below

exec sp_backup @backuplocation='c:\temp\',@overwrite='Y' ...

In the above command I would like to fine @backuplocation parameter details i.e 'C:\Temp'. Parameter name is constant in each job.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Parameter name is constant in each job. This should do it:

```
SELECT F1.command,
       O.splitdata
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(F.command, PATINDEX('%@backuplocation%', F.command), LEN(F.command)), ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS xmlfilter
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps F
    WHERE command LIKE '%--Should provide the default location%'
) F1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT fdata.D.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS splitdata
    FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') AS fdata(D)
) O;
```

so for example if I run it on my machine against our server:

```
SELECT F1.command,
       O.splitdata
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(F.command, PATINDEX('%@db_nm%', F.command), LEN(F.command)), ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS xmlfilter
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps F 
    WHERE F.command like 'exec dba..mnt_sts     @db_nm=''msdb'', @sts_object_recompile_fg=         0'
) F1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT fdata.D.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS splitdata
    FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') AS fdata(D)
) O;
```

this will return the following:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. Its not returning the parameter value. Its returning whole command.